# Docker Proxy Setup using environment variable

Tags: docker, proxy

While working behind the corporate proxies..

Why can't docker export the proxy specific value from environment variables
(`http_proxy, https_proxy,...`).

Usually you get timeout issue while pulling the image, even if the proxy url is mentioned in environment vairable.

I have to set the value (*hard-code the same value again*) in or by creating the config files in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d` folder.

If we change the proxy url, we have to make changes in different place. Or is there any way to refer the value from environment variable ?

I have tried the `docker run -e env_proxy_variable=proxy_url` but got the same timeout issue.

Comment: did you try to ping a url inside the container? quite a lot of times we have to set dns server as well

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the below instead:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://xxx:port/
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://xxx:port/
export FTP_PROXY=http://xxx:port/
```

You can hardcode these variables in the **/etc/default/docker** file so that they are exported whenever docker is started.

Comment: Yes. We can do that. But my Qus is shouldn't the docker and other tools(npm, mvn,...) export these values from the environment variables(HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, FTP_PROXY)

Comment: /etc/default/docker is a vendor specific directory that is not used by the upstream docker project. This is not portable and will break if you stop using the distribution vendor package.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the environment variable has been exported by typing $(name_of_var). For eg, after running

`docker run --env HTTP_PROXY="123.45.21.32" -it ubuntu_latest /bin/bash`

type

`echo $HTTP_PROXY`

It is likely that your DNS server isn't configured. Try

`cat /etc/resolv.conf`

if you see something like:

`nameserver:8.8.8.8`

then it's likely that the DNS server is inaccessible behind firewalls. You can pass dns server address along with `docker run` command like so:

`docker run --env HTTP_PROXY="123.45.21.32" --dns=172.10.18.0 -it ubuntu_latest /bin/bash`